# post_max_size and upload_max_size in php.ini has no effect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

I changed post_max_size and upload_max_size in my php.ini file inside C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12 and for some reason validation fails for large files in Laravel. Is there a reason for this?

I pressed the search key and modified the two in the php.ini file like this:

post_max_size = 200M

upload_max_filesize = 200M

Could there be another php.ini elsewhere? Am I modifying the right file? I am trying to make this work on localhost, so... I am thinking it has to be due because of a config file in Laravel.

I can upload small files, but I can't upload large files. Tried this on 10 small files and 10 large files, and there's no other explanation as to why large files don't pass all validation even if it shouldn't technically speaking.

Comment: Did you restart your web server?

Comment: I did it like 3 days ago, so it should work since I restarted the computer 3 times.

Comment: I just restarted it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know what php.ini did Laravel load, place this:

```
phpinfo(); exit;
```

as the very top of public/index.php file and run your app, looking for all php.ini files there.

Regards,

Comment: Weird because I edited it. Is there another php.ini file in the wamp directory?

Comment: Do you look at the `Loaded Configuration File` and `Additional .ini files parsed` in your phpinfo? Did you edited the right files? You have to research for yourself because it's a host specific issue. Then update your question how you do so far and we can continue debugging

Comment: /wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.10/bin (php.ini)* is the right file

Comment: Yes, that's the `Loaded Configuration File`, but you also have to look at `Additional .ini files parsed` because some ini file may overwrite the config

Comment: When editing the `php.ini` file in WAMPServer always use the menu links i.e. `wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini` this will ensure that you edit the file used by apache eg `/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.10/bin/php.ini` and not the `/wamp/bin/php/phpx.y.z/php.ini` which is only used by the `PHP CLI`